# Why does m2eclipse rename the modules when importing maven project from svn?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Basically there is a project I am new to that uses maven.  I have only used maven once before.  Anyway, I'm using the m2eclipse plugin.  The project is one root directory where all the modules are sub-projects.  I checked it in as a maven project and it created all the sub-projects correctly, but it changed the names of all the directories.

I have no idea why it did this, but this causes a lot of issues.  From this point forward the modules/projects can't be updated.  Neither normal synchronization nor "update maven" through the maven sub-menu works to update the project correctly.  And I obviously can't commit/share the projects anymore because the directory structure has changed.

So my question is what is the proper way to import the maven project from svn so that it doesn't do this?  I guess I also want to know WHY it does this?  It causes so many issues, why rename them?  I read somewhere that it's being renamed to the artifact Id... but like I said, I don't know why.

The alternative is to not use the m2eclipse plugin at all and instead utilize maven's eclipse:eclipse command (I believe that's the one).  Is there no way to make this work?

Thank you for your help and knowledge,

-Asaf

Comment: Are you SURE than Maven (or m2eclipse) actually changes your project's folder names from what they are on the SVN to something else when it works with them locally on your computer? Or is it just the displayed name in Eclipse (for the various modules) that changes (because the latter might be normal, you can configure m2eclipse with various naming patterns) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  I'm looking at the directory structure in my folders, not just in eclipse.  I just tried pulling in the projects separately and it did the same thing.  I'm kind of pulling my hair out in frustration over this.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and of m2eclipse are you using? Did you check that your projects have the same name in their POM's as the directories in which they reside in your Subversion repository? Do your projects have the same name in their POM's and in the corresponding .project Eclipse files?

Comment: You already answered my question below, but yes I did check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar structure, except that in my case sub-projects live in separate repositories and are connected to the main one via `svn:externals`. I perform check outs by choosing `Import -> SVN -> Project from SVN` and once everything has been checked out - and only the main project shows up in Eclipse - I select `Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects`.

At the end all my projects show up in Eclipse, no directory is modified, and version control works without problems.